# Blueprism Process From Control Room Can't See Elements on WebPage

Tags: blueprism

I have a process which uses a web application. The job runs perfectly from the process studio. In the control room it is encountering errors.
The process needs to select two text inputs, delete what is in there and pass in values. It then needs to click save. 
When I watch the process running, it seems to fail first time, on second attempt it updates the first one. However, for some reason the whole page then seems to scroll down? It then does not update the second input (even though the logs don't show this). Does anybody know why this would happen?
I have attached screenshots of process and log (I can't show web application as data is confidential and can't be changed)

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show the insides of "wait stage"? I suspect that you're not waiting for element "Claim status input".

The general good practice is to ensure first that element you want to interact does exist using wait stage.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using 6.x, you are correct in sending multiple actions at once.  Generally when using GSK, you want to activate the application first. I am not sure if that is what you are trying to do with the Claim Status Input Click Center. If however the page is changing based on that click, you would need another wiat stage after to make sure the page has updated.

Answer (score 0):

While Spying the elements, it may go wrong and spied element is not visible to BOT. After spying any element, uncheck the Parent attributes and the attributes which are having blank values, and try to highlight it.

The basic reason to uncheck the parent values are, it may happen that we do development in `dev` environment and the `url` are different in `dev` environment. Once we moved the process to either `UAT` or any other environment then, there are chances to have the different `URL`.

There the mis-match of attribute values for already spied element may occur and BOT will fail to identify the same element.